# CXF client don't work with ArrayOfType Axis service

Tags: axis, wsdl2java, cxf-client

I have this bean:

```
public class ListFrameTO implements Serializable
{
    private FrameTO[] frameTOs=null;

    public ListFrameTO() {
    }

    public FrameTO[] getFrameTOs() {
        return frameTOs;
    }

    public void setFrameTOs(FrameTO[] frameTOs) {
        this.frameTOs = frameTOs;
    }
}
```

axis converts it in:

```
<complexType name="ListFrameTO">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns2:TransferObject">
            <sequence>
                <element name="frameTOs" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_tns2_FrameTO"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
```

and

```
<complexType name="ArrayOf_tns2_FrameTO">
    <sequence>
        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="tns2:FrameTO"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

CXF client caused:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"xxx", local:"frameTOs"). Expected elements are <{xxx}item>
```

I need to convert `ArrayOf_tns2_FrameTO` in `FrameTO[]` in `cfx` client bean.

I don't use any custom binding file.